# How to pass boolean property value to angular forms disabled attribute?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying something like this to disable a form control dynamically based on a property value:

```
  pessoaFisica: boolean = true
```

```
      cnpj: [{ value: '', disabled: this.pessoaFisica }, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(14), Validators.maxLength(14)]],
```

I tested passing a property value to angular forms value property and it worked. Why it doenst work for disabled?

Answer (score 2):

Try to create the control of the form to FormControl:

```
cnpj: new FormControl(
  { value: '', disabled: this.pessoaFisica },
  [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(14), Validators.maxLength(14)]
),
```

If it doesn't work, check your html input, could be any remaining property that overwrite the typescript file.

Comment: All my controls are inside a form builder. Is there a way to do it inside it?

Comment: You could use a FormGroup instead a FormBuilder, it depends on the expected behaviour of the form. If you need to use the FormBuilder, your way to disabled with a variable is correct. You can also use this.form.controls['cnpj'].disable(); to disable manually on the ts

Comment: So my way is correct? for context: I have a conditional disable attribute in my template for this control, but it's null in the context i'm exposing here... so, i don't know if a disable set to null in html can interfere

Comment: Yes, your way is correct. The html overwrites the ts, so try to control the form control only through  the ts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use readonly instead of disabled in your template

```
<input [readonly]="property" type="text" name="control">
```

Comment: Yes, but if I do it in my template, I'll send the value of this control when submiting, and that's something I need to avoid